# PingFederate Grant Management Page does not log out with global HTML Form IdP adapter endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, adapter, openid, pingfederate

I am using PingFederate with OpenID Connect. And I am having an issue while logging out from the grant management page.

I configured my IdP adapter session state settings as global. So, if i use one of those Logout endpoints, i am being logged out from all other RPs successfully.

And after logout, if I try to get the grant management page via this endpoint **~/as/grants.oauth2**, login page is prompted so SLO works fine. But when i go the other endpoint which is **~/as/oauth_access_grants.ping** i can get the page without logging in. So, do you have any idea, why global HTML Form IdP adapter logout endpoint does not log me out from that endpoint and log me out from other endpoint?

I am using the endpoint which is defined on the adapter.

I have hierarchic adapters. A parent adapter holds the global settings and set as default. Children are accepting global settings too on their session settings.

So, when i call one of these adapter's endpoint (the ones shares global settings), all my sessions which has global settings are being removed from the session map. So a kind of selective SLO is happening.

I checked the server logs, each globally set adapters are added their sessions to the state map as HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:SESSION.

org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] getAttr(key: GEZIxxzzgrJ1Wq0vFoSY09, name: HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:SESSION

Even the grants management page.( ~/as/grants.oauth2). But the other grants management endpoint put its session to the states map as name: attrs and name: csrfToken.

[org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] getAttr(key: GEZIxxzzgrJ1Wq0vFoSY09, name: attrs) 2016-02-18 08:30:39,404 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] getAttr(key: GEZIxxzzgrJ1Wq0vFoSY09, name: csrfToken)

So basically when i revoke the session via adapter endpoint it removes all HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:SESSION values.

removeAttr(key: GEZIxxzzgrJ1Wq0vFoSY09, name: HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:SESSION) 2016-02-18 08:27:35,407 DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of removeA ttr on InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl state map size:11 attributes map size9 2016-02-18 08:27:35,409 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grou prpc.InterRequestStateMgmtGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY removeAttr() on [10.0.12.90:7600, 1 0.0.12.126:7600]

But the ones which is added by https://localhost:9031/as/oauth_access_grants.ping is still remains. So i can get the grants management page from this endpoint, but the other endpoint requires a login.

And I also tried idp/startSLO.ping logout endpoint.

It works and revokes all session (even the last one) ONLY if i get access token on that session.

Otherwise, if i login to the grants management page directly and call the idp/startSLO.ping, i get an error from server.

*###Server1### 2016-02-18 08:31:34,705 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.servlet.IntegrationControllerServlet] GET: https://localhost:9031/idp/startSLO.ping 2016-02-18 08:31:34,705 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [10.0.12.90:7600, 10.0.12.126:7600] 2016-02-18 08:31:34,708 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.IdpSessionRegistryMapImpl] getRegistered(3AeDfSHVS1F0JU4nwgLsPJ) found null authn beans 2016-02-18 08:31:34,708 DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of getRegistered on org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.IdpSessionRegistryMapImpl@e599115{bean->sessionLists=0, assertionId->bean=0, pfsessionid->beanSets=6} 2016-02-18 08:31:34,708 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.IdpSessionRegistryGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY getRegistered() on [10.0.12.90:7600, 10.0.12.126:7600] 2016-02-18 08:31:34,709 tid:b4ryqAPIEA6R0ywXzVmC6XtykHc DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.bindings.BindingServiceImpl] Not transporting protocol request message because the HTTP response has been committed (this is a normal condition usually due to an adapter or other component redirecting the user or writing its own content to the response).

SErver2
2016-02-18 08:31:34,706 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.IdpSessionRegistryMapImpl] getRegistered(3AeDfSHVS1F0JU4nwgLsPJ) found null authn beans 2016-02-18 08:31:34,707 DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of getRegistered on org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.IdpSessionRegistryMapImpl@dec9571{bean->sessionLists=0, assertionId->bean=0, pfsessionid->beanSets=6}*

And TRACK USER SESSIONS FOR LOGOUT and REVOKE USER SESSION ON LOGOUT is also enabled.

Basically, i need to find a way to make my grants management page use only the defaulthtmlform idp adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the /idp/startSLO.ping endpoint for logout? (and not a defined logout endpoint only on the adapter?)

I believe I was able to reproduce what you're seeing. I suspect you have "TRACK USER SESSIONS FOR LOGOUT" enabled in your OAuth Authorization Server Settings (part of the Asynchronous Front-Channel Logout mechanism ([documentation](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FasynchronousFrontChannelLogout.html)), but you don't have "REVOKE USER SESSION ON LOGOUT" (part of our server side tracking).

Try enabling "REVOKE USER SESSION ON LOGOUT" and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: please check may answer down.